# Функции push* и pop* для вектора

Tags: c++, vector

Пишу собственный вектор. Нужно адекватно написать функции типа `push_back()`, а ничего лучше, чем это в голову не лезет:

```
Vector<T> v(_size+1);

for(int i=0;i<_size;i++) 
{
    v.at(i) = ptr[i];
}
v.at(v._size-1) = value; 

delete[] this->ptr;

ptr = v.ptr;
_size = v._size;
```

Посоветуйте что-нибудь адекватное, пожалуйста.
Желательно идею, а не реализацию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это примерно так и делается. Для вашей реализации могу предложить несколько улучшений.
1) Лучше заказывайте просто сырую память. Мы же не хотим тратить ресурсы на создание объектов по-умолчанию? А вдруг там в конструкторе подключение к БД, или чтение файла с диска. Ресайз вашего вектора может занять кучу времени.
Получить кусок памяти под 10 объектов типа `T` можно вызовом `::operator new(sizeof(T) * 10);`
Заполнить сырую память существующими объектами поможет [std::uninitialized_copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/allocate/)

2) Заказывайте память с запасом. Увеличиваете размер в 2-3 раза. Такой ход позволит вам выполнять перезаказ памяти и копирование элементов гораздо реже.

3) Используйте *placement new* вместо *operator=*. Если вы последуете первому совету, то этот пункт можете считать не советом, а правилом, так как нельзя вызывать метод `operator=()` у неинициализированного участка памяти. Да и не обязан пользователь вашего вектора определять `operator=()`.
Таким образом такой код:

```
template<class T>
class Vector{
    T *items;
    //...
    void push(const T &value){
        //...
        items[size] = value;
        ++size;
    }
};
```

должен будет стать таким:

```
template<class T>
class Vector{
    T *items;
    //...
    void push(const T &value){
        //...
        new (items + size)(value);
        ++size;
    }
};
```

4) Что касается функции *pop*, не отдавайте уже занятую память. Она вполне может вам еще пригодиться. Для того, чтобы освободить лишнюю память лучше сделайте специальный метод. В `std::vector` он называется [shrink_to_fit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/)

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить, что реализации `shrink_to_fit` разрешено вообще ничего не делать.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно делают экспоненциальный рост внутреннего массива - это обеспечивает константное амортизированное время вставки элемента.

Выглядит это так. Есть внутренний массив, который не обязательно заполнен полностью. При добавлении элемента, если массив заполнен до конца - размер массива умножается на некоторое число. Обычно 2 или 1,5.

PS в вашей текущей реализации есть ошибка - вы сохраняете `v.ptr`, который должен быть уничтожен в деструкторе `v`.